# ¿como puedo obtener por SQL los pedidos de FROG descargados por el computo móvil?

Tags: sql

Buen día comunidad!
Algún experto que opere el sistema FROG, que pudiese orientar o apoyar en:
¿como puedo obtener por SQL los pedidos de FROG descargados por el computo móvil ?
Estaré al tanto de sus comentarios
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requieres usar 3 tablas al menos para ello, espero te ayude ésto.

```
SELECT
    BIT_ACTIVIDAD.CTECLI_CODIGO_K,
    BIT_ACTIVIDAD.CTEDIR_CODIGO_K,
    BIT_SUBACTIVIDAD.PEDCTE_REFERENCIA  
FROM
    BIT_BITACORA LEFT JOIN  BIT_ACTIVIDAD
    ON 
        BIT_BITACORA.SYSUDN_CODIGO_K  = BIT_ACTIVIDAD.SYSUDN_CODIGO_K
    AND BIT_BITACORA.SYSTRA_CODIGO_K  = BIT_ACTIVIDAD.SYSTRA_CODIGO_K
    AND BIT_BITACORA.BIT_SERIE_K      = BIT_ACTIVIDAD.BIT_SERIE_K
    AND BIT_BITACORA.BIT_FOLIO_K      = BIT_ACTIVIDAD.BIT_FOLIO_K
    LEFT JOIN BIT_SUBACTIVIDAD
    ON 
        BIT_BITACORA.SYSUDN_CODIGO_K  = BIT_SUBACTIVIDAD.SYSUDN_CODIGO_K
    AND BIT_BITACORA.SYSTRA_CODIGO_K  = BIT_SUBACTIVIDAD.SYSTRA_CODIGO_K
    AND BIT_BITACORA.BIT_SERIE_K      = BIT_SUBACTIVIDAD.BIT_SERIE_K
    AND BIT_BITACORA.BIT_FOLIO_K      = BIT_BITACORA.BIT_FOLIO_K 
WHERE 
     BIT_BITACORA.SYSUDN_CODIGO_K  ='PDTG'
 AND BIT_BITACORA.SYSTRA_CODIGO_K      ='FRBIT_BITACORA'
 AND BIT_BITACORA.BIT_SERIE_K          ='HH'
 AND BIT_BITACORA.BIT_FOLIO_K          = 1
 AND BIT_SUBACTIVIDAD.PEDCTE_REFERENCIA IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido de utilidad para realizar la consulta que requiero realizar.